# PHP MYSQL db reference error

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check my database to see if any user has a confirmcode identical to one a registering user enters on their registration form. However I keep getting the error:

```
"Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/elight5/public_html/test/student_register.php on line 15"
```

From what I can make out, that means there is an undefined variable but I know the values in the db are named appropriately.....Is there something wrong with my syntax? I have been using the same syntax across the site with no issues....

Any suggestions or errors about/in my code?

```
function confirmcode_exists($confirmcode){
    $confirmcode = sanitize($confirmcode);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `confirmcode` = '$confirmcode'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;

}
```

Comment: That error means your database connection is invalid - a failed connection gives you false, rather than a connection. You should add some debugging to see what's failing.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @andrewsi: That should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error for [`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/mysql_result) is stating that your MySQL query is failing.

Your actual SQL query does not look syntatically incorrect, which most likely means that either the table, or a column, is mispelled, or your connection doesn't have access to that table, or possibly that the connection is invalid altogether.

Try updating your code to the following; this should show you what your actual error is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `confirmcode` = '$confirmcode'");
if (!$result) {
    // query error
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
return (mysql_result($result, 0) == 1);
```